# Browserify, Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: requirejs, browserify, fullpage.js, iscroll

I'm using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) in a project, and according to the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs) you must add the `scrolloverflow.js` dependency in order to use some of the plugin's options.

I'm trying to manage all that with Browserify and I'm facing an issue when it comes to add that dependency.

The 'require' part of my code is like so:

```
jQuery = require('jquery')
require('../vendor/scrolloverflow.min.js')(jQuery)
require('../vendor/jquery.fullpage.min.js')
```

When I run the code I get that error in console, which breaks all the script:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

The error resides in the `scrolloverflow.min.js` script. Not having that much of experience with Browserify I guess the problem has something to do with the way I'm requiring the script, but don't have any idea how to fix that.

Comment: Adding a reproduction of it would help.

Comment: @Alvaro, [here](http://dapp.cloud.fgv.br/validar/observatorio-do-rio) it is.

Comment: The site won't load.